# Public Facing Contact Form

Tags: list, form, contacts

I'm looking to add a basic contact form to a public facing sharepoint 2013 website.

I know that this topic is a highly requested across the interwebs and there is very little answers for new users. But I have come across the same two answers (multiple times) and hope that some here can help clarify things for us new Sharepoint Devs.

The [Contact Us Form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-Contact-Us-Form-app-to-your-website-4d6133f7-2aaa-4cb0-9e0d-bebbfefd00e6) app from the Microsoft Store does work to an extent. However, should you want to add it to a pop up modal or edit the code in someway then you'll run in to problems. Also, it seems impossible to edit the styles for these contact forms.

Moving on to solution number 2 - [this is a pop up contact form](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/30/create-a-quick-contact-us-or-feedback-form-in-sharepoint-2013-using-callouts/) which works great... for registered and logged in users. Obviously a bad choice for anonymous users or the general public.

I've been reading up on allowing list access to anonymous users but this seems to be very cumbersome and cannot reach the desired result.

Has anyone any advice on either adding access to the second form option above or indeed another contact solution at all?

Comment: Sorry if it's a lame question, is it SharePoint Online or SharePoint Public-Facing license?

Comment: Sorry, this is probably a lame answer - I'm not sure. The client had set it up before I joined the project. How would I know which is which?
I do use Sharepoint/Office365 via browsers and via Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Comment: Actually I have no idea about SharePoint Online, but Office 365 means SharePoint Online I guess.. let someone else jump in

Comment: Thanks anyway Arsalan. If you have any leads on what to look in to that would help also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last answer is quite outdated by now, I would recommend looking into this - [Creating a web form with Data Table and saving data into SharePoint lists](https://plumsail.com/docs/forms/how-to/data-table-to-sp.html)

It's a newer product and allows to do exactly that - public form that adds items to SP via Flow, no need for users to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution recently provided on CodeProject that has use of forms for public facing sites with the help of form designer.
Sharepoint online does not provide an interface to provide anonymous users access to lists but there is a custom solution that will provide a UI to achieve this.

More details here: [Publish a Form for Anonymous Users on a Public Site in Office 365](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/785099/Publish-a-Form-for-Anonymous-Users-on-a-Public-Sit)

Comment: Hi RansherSpeaks, Thanks for your reply. This seems like it may be a valid solution but the use of Forms Designer takes away from it.

Would you know if it's possible to use this solution without it?

Comment: I think you will have to borrow from solution 2 that you mentioned in your OP to create the custom form using callouts. The anonymous access to the list you can achieve with the WSP in my link above.